# How to coalesce rows(X columns each) with same values for 3 columns in sqlite3 and prioratize the coalesce by a specific column vlaue?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, t-sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3(interacting via python3) db table(named "T") that looks like -

```
ID(PK)  A            B    ....  M  ....  N .....   P ..... X
_____________________________________________________________

 1  "string1"   "tom"       "Jim"    "Subway"   NULL    "Mr.Sub"
 2  "string2"   "tom"       "Jim"    "Hungry"   NULL    "Mr.Sub"
 3  "string3"   "tom"       "Jim"     NULL     "XBOX"   "Mr.Sub"
 4  "string1"   "Pam"       "Dave"    NULL     "GOLF"  "Starbucks"
 5  "string2"   "Pam"       "Dave"   "Arbys"    NULL   "Starbucks"
 6  "string1"   "Kyle"      "Ron"     NULL      NULL    "Gamers"
 7  "string4"   "Kyle"      "Ron"     NULL     "CART"   "Gamers"
```

I want to do the following operations on it -

1. Find all unique combinations of columns B,M and X.
2. For each such combination, find how many corresponding rows exist.
3. If there are more than 1 row per such B,M and X combination, merge them into one row by following steps.
4. In these rows, if there are conflicts in values for other columns(N,P etc) select the columns' value from the row which has A="string1". If A is NULL go with any other non Null value. If all values are NULL, then go with NULL.

For the example above, the resultant table should be like -

```
ID(PK)  A            B    ....  M  ....  N ..... P ....   X
____________________________________________________________

 1  "string1"   "tom"       "Jim"    "Subway"  "XBOX"   "Mr.Sub"
 4  "string1"   "Pam"       "Dave"   "Arbys"   "GOLF"   "Starbucks"
 6  "string1"   "Kyle"      "Ron"     NULL     "CART"   "Gamers"
```

The solution I could come up with was :

```
update a
set a.N = coalesce(a.N, b.N)
set a.P = coalesce(a.P, b.P)
from T a inner join T b
on a.B = b.B and a.M = b.M and a.X = b.X
```

This was based on an example for mysql given in the blog post [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/442428/How-to-update-a-row-with-another-row-if-column-val). However this doesn't work in sqlite3 and lacks prioritization based on column A values. Can someone share the right query that would work in sqlite3?

Comment: (X columns each) not (N columns each)

Comment: Coalesece doesn't do what you think it does. It replaces a `NULL` columns value with another placeholder.  Also, in addition to an `UPDATE` you're going to need a `DELETE` to remove the old data.  Maybe you should tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: I have a database that has observations for firms multiple(mostly 2, maximum 4) times a year(corresponding to column A values say p1,p2,p3,p4), as most of the information is going to be same, I want to collapse all the information to only once a year and hence keep the values for row with column A=p1 in case the columns might have different values.

Comment: Again, you're using `coalesce` incorrectly here. You want to _combine_ or _aggregate_ certain _rows_, not columns, which have something in common.

Comment: Thanks Tim, how do I go about what I want to do ? I dont want to combine per se(I want to stick with just one value(corresponding to say, row with A=p1) not concatenate them).

Comment: Update your question and show more data.  Note that the language "first row" and "second row" don't mean anything unless you can tell us a column or logic for what makes one row the first one.  Also, let us know if every record would be paired when grouping by B, M, X, or could there be single rows, or triples etc.

Comment: Tim, thanks for your suggestion. I updated my question, hope it's more clear what I want to get.

Comment: Is `string1` the smallest value?

Comment: Hi CL, No but it's a fixed value.

Comment: Does a row with `string1` exist in each group?

Comment: Yes, it will always exist. Also, If you can help me with picking up any available non NULL  value(unless all values are NULL) and let go of the prioritization by column A, that'd be great too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide a `.dump` from SQLite command line tool of a suitably tailored toy database; as a [mcve]. I.e. show all required "create table ..." and "insert into ..." lines to recreate the environment you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

The merge operation can be described as follows:

1. For each `string1` row, if the `N` or `P` values are NULL, take them from some other row with a non-NULL value in the same `B`/`M`/`X` group.
2. Delete all other `stringX` rows.

```sql
UPDATE T
SET N = (SELECT N
         FROM T AS T2
         WHERE T2.B = T.B
           AND T2.M = T.M
           AND T2.X = T.X
           AND T2.N IS NOT NULL)
WHERE A = 'string1'
  AND N IS NULL;

UPDATE ...   -- same for P

DELETE FROM T
WHERE A <> 'string1';
```

Comment: What do you mean with "N type" and "merge"? Show an example.

Comment: Hi CJ, I have edited my question. Please see the stuff highlighted.

Comment: Show an example.

Comment: I have edited my example to be very detailed now. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am afraid this question is now buried. Not sure how SO works, is there a chance folks are seeing this ?